# CakePHP: Display form post value in ctp file from controller

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently working on a CakePHP web application I have already created `form` in `view.ctp` and `form submitted` through ajax, but when I try to display form value in `add.ctp` from controller which is not showing.

When I print or echo variable in controller value is showing, how can I get value and display in `add.ctp` file?

I want ajax post form data from `view.ctp` to controller file and i want to see form data in `add.ctp` file from controller? CakePHP version is 2.0.13

**View.ctp**

```
<?php echo $form->create('Review',array('action'=>'add/'.$listingData['Listing']['id'].'','id'=>'saveForm')); 

echo $form->input("starrating",array(
                    'title'=>__("Eek! Methinks not"),
                    'type'=>'radio',
                    'options'=>array('1' => '1'),
                    'class'=>'hover-star',
                    'value'=>'testing',

)
);  

echo $form->input("starrating",array(
                    'title'=>__("Meh. I've experienced better"),
                    'type'=>'radio',
                    'options'=>array('2' => '2'),
                    'class'=>'hover-star',
                    'value'=> '2',

)
);

echo $form->input("starrating",array(
                    'title'=>__("A-OK"),
                    'type'=>'radio',
                    'options'=>array('3' => '3'),
                    'class'=>'hover-star',
                    'value'=> '3',

)
);  

echo $form->input("starrating",array(
                    'title'=>__("Yay! I'm a fan"),
                    'type'=>'radio',
                    'options'=>array('4' => '4'),
                    'class'=>'hover-star',
                    'value'=> '4',

)
);

echo $form->input("starrating",array(
                    'title'=>__("Woohoo! As good as it gets!"),
                    'type'=>'radio',
                    'options'=>array('5' => '5'),
                    'class'=>'hover-star',
                    'value'=> '5',

)
);      


echo $form->end(); ?>
```

**Add Ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->pageStarRating;?>
```

**Ajax & Javascript **

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.hover-star').rating({

        focus: function (value, link) {
                $("#hover-test").css("color", "#000");
                var tip = $('#hover-test');
                tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);

        },
        blur: function (value, link) {
                var tip = $('#hover-test');
                $('#hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');

        },

        click: function (value, link) {
                var tip = $('#hover-test');
                tip.empty();


        },

        callback: function(value, link){
                var tip = $('#stick');
                tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);

            }

        });

        $(".hover-star").click(function () {
            $("#hover-test").css("color", "#ff6a00");
            $('#saveForm').submit();

        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#saveForm').submit(function() {
                    var formData = $(this).serialize();
                    var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');

                      $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: formUrl,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                            //alert(data);
                            window.location = formUrl;

                            },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

**Controller File**

```
if($this->Review->save($this->data))

{   
    echo $add=$this->data['Review']['starrating']; 

}

$this->pageStarRating = $add;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? _how can i get value and display in add ctp file_ does this mean you want to post with ajax and see that value at the same time on the same page?? What version of cake are you using? You already asked similar question where you received answer for your question but it seems to me that you don't know what you want there...

Comment: @skywalker no i want ajax post form data from view.ctp to controller file and i want to see form data in add ctp file from controller? cakephp version is 2.0.13

Comment: Like the name of the file says, it's for the _viewing_ of data, what kind of data are you trying to post from view that you can't retrieve from database from add action? Are you editing or adding reviews?

Comment: @skywalker yes adding review star rating

Comment: @skywalker here example of http://code.runnable.com/Vk8T6Af4rb0RfJjb/output same thing i want to do with my web application

Comment: Then you have to use ajax to post to some controller aciton and there save star rating to db, and in `add` action in your controller retrieve data from db and show it on add page, seems pretty straightforward to me. That page doesn't exit.

Comment: @skywalker can u give me example of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95700/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-skywalker).